# ssh to remote Linux for mysql query command

Tags: mysql, bash

I am using ssh key to login to remote Linux server to get result of some commands. This part is working fine. Now I have made a bash script which actually query an DB size of mysql server on that remote linux server. Script is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to query mysql stats
#set -x
HOST="192.168.0.1"
USER="root"
PASS="PASSSSS"
DB="radius"
CMD=`ssh -p 12345 $HOST mysql -u$HOST -p$PASS --skip-column-names -e "SELECT table_schema "$DB", sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema='radius' GROUP BY table_schema;"`
F=`echo $CMD | cut -f1 -d"." | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
echo $F
echo $F
```

But when I run this script. it gives following error

```
# ./qmysql.sh
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `mysql -u192.168.0.1 -pPASSSS --skip-column-names -e SELECT table_schema radius, sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema='radius' GROUP BY table_schema;'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try replace **`** to **"** and skip **all** the quotes

```
 CMD="ssh -p 12345 $HOST mysql -u$HOST -p$PASS --skip-column-names -e \"SELECT table_schema \"$DB\", sum(data_length + index_length)/1024/1024  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema='radius' GROUP BY table_schema;\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some Problems with quotes.

Try something like

```
... "SELECT table_schema \"$DB\", sum( ...
```

Comment: ok sill its giving error:
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Updated:
Final line that worked for me is

>>> CMD=`ssh -p $PORT $HOST mysql -uroot '-pSQLPASS' --skip-column-names -e '"SELECT' table_schema '"radius",' 'sum(data_length' + 'index_length)' FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE 'table_schema='\''radius'\''' GROUP BY 'table_schema;"' | cut -f1 -d"." | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` <<<

Comment: however the variables didn't worked inside quotes, I had to use the password/dbname in CMD instead of variables.